# Did griffons exist in the My Little Pony franchise before G4?

Tags: history, my-little-pony

The first, a griffon character in *[My Little Pony: Friendship Is Magic](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/My_Little_Pony_Friendship_is_Magic)*, appeared in episode 5 of season 1. Did the griffons appear in any of the three earlier generations, or is this their first appearance in the franchise?

I didn't see all the earlier series, movies and comics before G4.

Comment: https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/Griffons

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, that is the G4 entry...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Gosh. It's a good job I didn't post it as an answer...

Comment: A person called Tom Griffin was executive producer to some G1 TV series episodes. Does that count? Otherwise, I found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. G1 and G2 only had ponies, pegasi and unicorns (plus some odd winged unicorns that were [animation](https://derpynews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/surprise-alicorn2.png) [mistakes](http://mylittlewiki.org/w/images/f/f4/Dazzleglowcartoon.jpg)). The various cartoons also introduced human friends as well as a solitary dragon, mud-monsters, spiderlings, bushwoolies (don't ask), porcines, zebras, goats, flowerlings, monkeys, bulldogs and leprechauns as the antagonists.

G3 introduced a raft of new [animal friends](https://mylittleponyg3.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Non-Pony) including ladybugs, birds, and mer-ponies but no griffons.

G4 then introduced all sorts of other animals such as cows, adult horses, griffons, cats, deer, Klugetown monsters, mermares, hippogriffs and Transformers (both Autobots and Decepticons).